# Wanted but not invoke: Mockito test

Tags: unit-testing, exception, testing, mockito, invokerequired

I have a problem.
I don't understand why mockito go in exception. 
RecordWriter write a Record into the file. I want verify if it write or not. 
I implemented another function and i tried to mock(OutputStream.class), but the result is the same. My current test is:

```
    try (RecordWriter writer = new RecordWriter(serverAlias))
            {
            RecordWriter wr = mock(RecordWriter.class);
            writer.writeRecordToFile(httpRecord.printRecord().getBytes(CHARSET_UTF8));
            verify(wr,times(1)).writeRecordToFile(httpRecord.printRecord().getBytes(CHARSET_UTF8));

            }
```

**The exception is:**

```
Wanted but not invoked:
recordWriter.writeRecordToFile(
    [50, 48, 49, 54, 48, 51, 49, 56, 45, 49, 50, 49, 52, 49, 51, 44, 50, 48, 49, 54, 48, 51, 49, 56, 49, 49, 50, 50, 44, 50, 48, 49, 54, 48, 51, 49, 56, 49, 49, 50, 57, 44, 51, 51, 51, 54, 53, 52, 56, 55, 57, 56, 44, 112, 114, 111, 118, 97, 44, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 105, 32, 100, 111, 110, 39, 116, 32, 107, 110, 111, 119, 10]
);
-> at report.RecordWriterTest.setup(RecordWriterTest.java:72)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at report.RecordWriterTest.setup(RecordWriterTest.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: You are not calling the writeRecordToFile method on the mock.

Comment: Thx. I have some function in RecordWriting which block the writing. For example if the size of directory is > of 2MB, ReportWriting no write more. Is possible test it with mockito if I call wr.writeRecordToFile()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the writeRecordToFile method on the mock.

You have:

1) a real instance -  `RecordWriter writer = new RecordWriter(serverAlias)`

2) a mock - `RecordWriter wr = mock(RecordWriter.class);`

and you call the method on the real instance (writer) and try to verify if the mock (wr) was interacted with.

Change the method call to: `wr.writeRecordToFile(httpRecord.printRecord().getBytes(CHARSET_UTF8));`

and it should work. Although it seems quite a pointless test, if you ask me.

Comment: Thx. I have some function in RecordWriting which block the writing. For example if the size of directory is > of 2MB, ReportWriting no write more.  Is  possible test it with mockito if I call wr.writeRecordToFile()?